Quotient of Graded Rings $S \to S/f$ inducing Homeomorphism on Proj
Let $A$ be a Noetherian ring, and let $X$ be a closed subscheme of of $\mathbb{P}^r_A$. We define the homogeneous
coordinate ring $S:=S(X)$ of $X$ for the given embedding to be $A[x_0, ..., x_r]/I$ (with induced grading),
where $I=I(X)$ is some homogenous ideal defining $X$. (note that there are many homogeneous ideals $I(X)$ defining same closed $X \subset \mathbb{P}^r_k$, but there exist a unique saturated $I^{\text{sat}}$ one; the "biggest" one with resp. having $X$ as resulting scheme; cp with question).
Let $f \in S_d \subset S$ (i.e. $f$ of degree $d$) be a non zero homogeneous element such that the canonical quotient map $S \to S/(f)$ of graded rings induces a homeomorphism $\text{Proj} \ S/(f) \to \text{Proj} \ S $ of underlying proj schemes.
Question: What can we say about this $f \in S$? More concretely, can we decide when is it a zero divisor or even nilpotent?
(Note, that in affine situation it's always nilpotent - see also below how this fact interplays with "projective" situation  - so here I want to understand the analogous situation on level of Proj construction & homogeneous coordinate ring instead of Spec). I'm primary interested in following three cases:

for arbitrary homogenous ideal $I \subset A[x_0, ..., x_r]$

for ideal $ I$ saturated: ie if for $f \in A[x_0, ..., x_r]$ there exist for each $i=0,1,...,r$ a positive integer $n_i$ such that $ f \cdot x_i^{n_i} \in I$, then $f \in I$

with $I$ is saturated as in 2. and additionally $X$ is integral (=reduced and irreducible) scheme
(The last question closely related with this question and I strongly conjecture in case $A=k$ field under assumptions in 3. one can show that $S$ is a domain; what would be equivalent that every such $f$ must be zero


Let compare it firstly with affine situation with a fing $R$, then if $f \in R$ such that $R \to R/(f)$ induces homeomorphism on specs, then $f$ is nilpotent.
From this we can conclude that for every $s \in S_1$ the element $f/s^d \in S_{(s)}$ (inside the degree-$0$ part of the localization) is nilpotent.
And if I'm not missing something, then this would already suffice to show that initial $f$ is nilpotent as element in homogenoeus ring $S$, as we have natural inclusion $S_{(s)} \subset S_s $ and inside the latter $f= (f/s^d) \cdot s^d$ is by above nilpotent,
and so we can conclude that $f$ is nilpotent in $S$.
Firstly, is the argumentation correct? If yes, then we can answer the 3 questions as follows:
For (1) we can only state that it's nilpotent, nothing more. Can we say something more in case (2) if the ideal $I$ is saturated?
The case (3) seems to be more restructive: As $S_{(s)}$ is domain, this implies that $f/s^d$ is zero or equivtly that $s^d \cdot f=0$ (by univ prop of localization) for every $s \in S_1$. But this already implies (since $S$ Noetherian) that $f \in I$ as $I$ is assumed to be saturated, so $f=0$ in $ S$.
Let's come back to my concern in
If I'm haven't overseen some mistake in my reasonings, then it seems that the case (3) answers the question if for integral $X$ the homogeneous ring $S$ in construction is a domain:
If not, there exist two (wlog homogeneous; otherwise take summands of highest degrees) nonzero $f,g \in S$ with $f \cdot g=0$. Then, on level of topology (as a scheme carries an underlying top space) we have
$X= \text{Proj} \ S= \text{Proj} \ S/(f \cdot g)= \text{Proj} \ S/(f) \cup \text{Proj} \ S/(g)$.
As $X$ irreducible, wlog $X=\text{Proj} \ S/(f)$ on level of topological spaces. Then applying case (3) from above we deduce $f=0$.
Does the argument work? (I have bad feeling with "topological" part above - especially does the last equation hold in general setting - and because Hartshorne in the Exercise II.5.14(a) from question linked above explicitly assumes $A=k$ algebraically closed (...presumably he intended to use Nullstellensatz) while the approach I presented above not exploits it. So I'm sure, probably my approach is flawed.
So finally conflating my original concern about properties of $f \in S$ with it's connection to Hartshorne's exercise in linked question in the way I tried to explain so far, are my considerations exposed above on posed questions correct or are there some (serious/ irreparable?) error(s) hidden?
Especially, do we really need $k$ to to assume to be algebraically closed in the quoted Exercise as Hartshorne requires (that which is particularly gnawing in the story)

If $X$ is Noetherian, normal, connected, it is integral (normal local rings are integral domains).  For your question #3, you certainly don't need algebraically closed to deduce that $S$ is a domain.  Indeed, you don't need $A$ to be a field either.  I believe the homogeneous primes in $S$ not containing $S_+$ correspond quite generally to the integral subschemes of $\mathrm{Proj} S$.  Note, homogeneous primes are always saturated.

@KarlSchwede: so the statement in part (3) is true, but is the argumentation I gave above also correct? Also, coming back to initial question, is it also true that quotating by nilpotent elements behave for proj construction in "same" way as for affine situation?

Namely, we know that if $R$ is a Noetherian ring and $f \in R$, then the canonical closed immersion $\text{Spec}(R/(f)) \to \text{Spec}(R)$ induced by $R \to R/f$ is homeomorphism (on topol level) iff $f$ is nilpotent (...essentially by univ property of nilpotent ideal). Now the question is does the same holds for Projs? ie, if $S$ homogeneous Noeth ring with (wlog homogeneous $f \in S$) is the canonical canonical closed immersion $\text{Proj}(S/(f)) \to \text{Proj}(S)$ a homeo iff $f$ is nilpotent as element of $S$.

The direction "$f$ nilpotent -> homeom" is trivial, what about the other one. First of all, is it true? I tried to give a argument above, is it fine or do you some gaps?
